# Preload Data for Data Bound JS for SEO

Tags: javascript, rivets.js

I am using Rivets.js, but I think the question applies to any JS library that binds data to a template.

I love the idea of setting up templates and the just passing JSON back and forth between the server and client. However, the issue comes up about Initial loading of content, especially in regards to SEO Content. Since the page will only load initially empty templates like:

```
<h1>{ page.title }</h1>
<ul>
  <li rv-each-item="page.list"><a rv-href="item.href">{ item.title }</a></li>
</ul>
```

which is not very search engine friendly. I know SEO takes a hit when building a dynamic app, but I was wondering if there was any way to be able to set default text, and then have the JS "overwrite" it once it's loaded. This helps with the display on initial load as well as for search engines. Maybe something like this.

```
<h1 rv-text="page.title">Super SEOy title</h1>
<ul>
  <li rv-each-item="page.list">
    <a rv-href="item.href" rv-text="item.title" href="/seo/link">Super SEOy List Item</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/second/link">Third Super SEOy List Item</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/third/link">Third Super SEOy List Item</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it looks like what I was wanting to do is already possible. I just set an rv-if="p.notLoaded" on the attributes I want to hide once the JS data loads.